scaffold db/add identity 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`' whil attempting to activate 'Context'.'
I scaffolded my db to create the initial context and now adding identity when running  Add-Migration init -context routermaincontext I get the following error:
An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory1[RouterMain.Models.Contact] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory1[RouterMain.Models.Contact]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions1[RouterMain.Data.RouterMainContext]' while attempting to activate 'RouterMain.Data.RouterMainContext'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager1[RouterMain.Models.Contact] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager1[RouterMain.Models.Contact]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions1[RouterMain.Data.RouterMainContext]' while attempting to activate 'RouterMain.Data.RouterMainContext'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore1[RouterMain.Models.Contact] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: RouterMain.Data.RouterMainContext': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions1[RouterMain.Data.RouterMainContext]' while attempting to activate 'RouterMain.Data.RouterMainContext'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator1[RouterMain.Models.Contact]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions1[RouterMain.Data.RouterMainContext]' while attempting to activate 'RouterMain.Data.RouterMainContext'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator1[RouterMain.Models.Contact]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions1[RouterMain.Data.RouterMainContext]' while attempting to activate 'RouterMain.Data.RouterMainContext'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager1[RouterMain.Models.Contact] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager1[RouterMain.Models.Contact]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions1[RouterMain.Data.RouterMainContext]' while attempting to activate 'RouterMain.Data.RouterMainContext'.) Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'routermaincontext'. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions1[RouterMain.Data.RouterMainContext]' while attempting to activate 'RouterMain.Data.RouterMainContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
Ive been trying to resolve this but have had no luck any help would be appreciated.
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<ProdMainContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString"));
        });


        // Add services to the container.

        //builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<RouterMainContext>();

        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

        //Add Authentication
        builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme);
        // Add Authorization
        builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder();

        builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<Contact>()
            .AddUserStore<RouterMainContext>()
            .AddApiEndpoints();

        var app = builder.Build();

        app.MapIdentityApi<Contact>();

    public class RouterMainContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {

        protected RouterMainContext(DbContextOptions options)
            : base(options) { }

        public RouterMainContext(DbContextOptions<RouterMainContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }

public partial class ProdMainContext : RouterMainContext
{

    public ProdMainContext(DbContextOptions<ProdMainContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Company> Companys { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Service> Services { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Contact> AppUsers { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }



    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Job>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.InvoiceId, "IX_Jobs_InvoiceId");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.UserId, "IX_Jobs_UserId");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Invoice).WithMany(p => p.Jobs).HasForeignKey(d => d.InvoiceId);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.Jobs).HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<LineItem>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.JobId, "IX_LineItems_JobId");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Job).WithMany(p => p.LineItems).HasForeignKey(d => d.JobId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Service>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.CompanyId, "IX_Services_CompanyId");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Company).WithMany(p => p.Services).HasForeignKey(d => d.CompanyId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.CompanyId, "IX_Users_CompanyId");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Company).WithMany(p => p.Users).HasForeignKey(d => d.CompanyId);
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}

Ive tried everything I could find on this issue but none being the same issue that I am having.
